# group total based on months difference

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

data frame:

```
ID spend month_diff    
12  10    -5
12  10    -4
12  10    -3
12  10     1         
12  10    -2         
12  20     0        
12  30     2         
12  10    -1
```

I want to get the `spend_total` based on the month difference for a particular ID. `month_diff` in negative means spend done by customer in last year and positive means this year. So, I want to compare the spend of customers for past year and this year. so the conditions are as follows:
Conditions:

- `if month_diff >= -2 and < 0` then cumulative spend for negative months -> `flag=pre`
- `if month_diff > 0 and <=2` then  cumulative spend for positive months  -> `flag=post`

Note: the no. of `month_diff +ve` and `-ve` are not same. it might be the case that customer had 4 transactions in `-ve month_diff` and only 2 transaction on `+ve` so I want to take only 2 month cumulative sum of `-ve month_diff` and 2 for `+ve` and don't want to consider the spend where `month_diff` is 0.

Desired data frame:

```
ID spend month_diff spend_tot   flag    
12  10    -2         20         pre
12  30     2         40        post
```

40 is the cumulative sum of spend for month_diff +1 and +2 (i.e. 10+30) and same for month_diff -1 and -2 and its cumulative spend is 20(i.e.10 + 10

Comment: @jezrael updated.

Comment: 0 month_diff does not split data into groups. Leave it or just suppose we have filtered out that rows. only cumulate the sum of spend based on positive and -ve months and the logic is specified in conditions stated above.

Comment: 40 is the cumulative sum of spend. for month_diff +1 and +2 (i.e. 10+30) and same for month_diff -1 and -2 and its cumulative spend is 20(i.e.10 + 10) .These rows are processing based on the conditions that I have mentioned in the question

Comment: if month_diff >= -2 and < 0 then cumulative spend for negative months -> flag=pre
if month_diff > 0 and <=2 then cumulative spend for positive months -> flag=post ….


this is the logic, that I have specified in the question itself

Comment: if I would have known the solution, then why would I post a question here.  :|

Comment: I have just given an example it can be -1 -2 anything value of month diff does not matter. what matter is value of spend_tot (i.e. cumulative sum). if you change input data by 12 10 3 how does that matter. I have stated the conditions that I want sum of +ve 2 months and -ve 2 months.

Comment: OK, last thing. Is posible only `1` and `-1` or `2, -2` per group ? Or there is always pairs `1, -1` and `2, -2` ?

Comment: per group means per ID (i.e 12) which represents a customer transaction ID. and months_diff are not in sequence as mentioned in input data. No pairs basically.

Comment: so is necessary filter pairs and only them processing rigth?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#filter values by list
df = df[df['month_diff'].isin([1,2,-1,-2])]

#filter duplicated values with absolute values of month_diff
df = df[df.assign(a=df['month_diff'].abs()).duplicated(['ID','a'], keep=False)]
#sign column
a = np.sign(df['month_diff'])
#aggregate sum and last
df1 = (df.groupby(['ID', a])
         .agg({'month_diff':'last', 'spend':'sum'})
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())

df1['flag'] = np.select([df1['month_diff'].ge(-2) & df1['month_diff'].lt(0),
                         df1['month_diff'].gt(0) & df1['month_diff'].le(2)], 
                         ['pre','post'], default='another val')
print (df1)
   ID  month_diff  spend  flag
0  12          -1     20   pre
1  12           2     40  post
```